# How do you evaluate $f(x_n)$?

Tags: real-analysis

I am not sure I am clear on how to evaluate the $f(x_n)$; what the it mean to evaluate the function of a sequence?

Comment: You evaluate $f$ at $x_n$...

Comment: If $x_n\in$ domain of $f$ then have sense speak of an image or of a set enumerable   of images.

Comment: So whatever $x_n$ converges to?  So if $x_n \rightarrow c$ then $f(x_n) = f(c)$?

Comment: @spitfiredd That happens iff $f$ is continuous - it is in fact a definition of continuous functions.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing $x_n$ and $\{x_n\}$, which mean two different things, and the notation totally is confusing here at first. $x_n$ is just an ordinary old number, and $f(x_n)$ is $f$ evaluated at the number $x_n$, just like $f(a)$ is $f$ evaluated at $a$. In particular, it is the $n$th term of the *sequence* $\{x_n\}$. This is where the notation can be a little confusing at first: $n$ is a natural number, $x_n$ is a number (or maybe something else if you're in some more exotic space), $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence. You're right that it would be confusing to figure out what would be meant by $f(\{x_n\})$, since $f$ is a function whose arguments ought to be numbers and not sequences.

However, we are often interested in the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}=f(x_1),f(x_2),\dots.$

Comment: ...and to be really precise, we should write the sequence as $\{x_n\}_n$, or even $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$, to indicate that $n$ is the index variable for the sequence.  In this simple case, it may seem obvious enough, but there's a big difference between, say, the sequences $\{a^b\}_a$ and $\{a^b\}_b$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concrete example: for the sequence $\{x_n\} = \left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}$, $f(x) = x^2$, the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ is equal to $\left\{\frac{1}{n^2}\right\}$.

You aren't taking 'the function of a sequence,' per se.  You're taking the 'function of a number' at every term of the sequence $\{x_n\}$, and using this to build a new sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us, say, for example, $f(x)=x^2$. Then, the sequence $(x_n)=1,2,3,4,...$ gets mapped to 
$f(x_n)=1,4,9,16,...$.

You take each element of $(x_n)$ and evaluate $f(x_i)$ (the value of the function at the $i$th element of $(x_n)$), as long as $x_i$ is in the domain of $f$, giving you a new sequence:
$$f:(x_n)\to f(x_n)$$